# Amplicar margen en gráfico

Tags: r

Hago un gráfico de unos datos y me sale tal que así.

```
p %>%
  ggplot( aes(y=Y1, x=X1,  fill=Y1)) +
    geom_density_ridges(alpha=0.5) +
    theme_light() +
    theme(
      legend.position="none",
      strip.text.x = element_text(size = 5)
    ) +
  labs(title = "Titulo", 
       x = "Titulo x", 
       y = "")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y1 es de tipo factor, y x1 numérica

Digamos el que dibujo toca el margen superior y se corta, y no consigo
ampliar el margen de la parte superior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En `ggplot2` no se puede modificar el margen como tal, como se haría con los gráficos base. Podrías usar `exapand_limits()` para aumentar el área del gráfico y obtener un resultado similar.

No puedo reproducir tu ejemplo porque no están disponibles los datos. Pongo un código que funciona:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species)) +
  geom_density_ridges2() +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0.01, 0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.01, 0)) +
  theme_ridges() + 
    expand_limits(y = c(-1, 5))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es a partir de uno de los ejemplos que trae `ggridges` y en este caso expandiendo el límite de `y` desde -1 hasta 5 se logra agregar espacio abajo y arriba. Está un poco exagerado para que se vea lo que hace. La expansión dependerá de la cantidad de elementos que tenga `y`, podrías probar con diferentes valores.

No da un control tan fino como `margins=` en gráficos base, pero podría resolver tu problema.